# In GCP Dataproc Serverless, it's not writing to Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have a query with a limit 1000  against a Cassandra instance and want to write it to Bigtable. I'm using the python templates in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-templates/tree/main/python/dataproc_templates/gcs as a guide (Cassandra to Bigquery and GCS to Bigtable) to create a Cassandra to Bigtable.

The batch is running over 2 hours before I cancel it.

It shows submitting 6372 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage.

I've double-checked the hbase-site.xml in the container I upload.  I would expect some kind of error if something were mis-configured..

I also wouldn't expect it to run more than a few minutes.

It shows tasks as finishing, and there are now rows saved to the Bigtable table.

Here's the relevant code snippet.

```
spark = (
            SparkSession.builder.appName("CassandraToBT")
            .config(constants.SQL_EXTENSION, constants.CASSANDRA_EXTENSION)
            .config(f"spark.sql.catalog.casscon", constants.CASSANDRA_CATALOG)
            .config(
                f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog}.spark.cassandra.connection.host",
                input_host,
            )
            .config(f"spark.cassandra.auth.username", input_username)
            .config(f"spark.cassandra.auth.password", input_password)
            .getOrCreate()
        )
        print(spark.sql("SHOW NAMESPACES FROM casscon").show(), flush=True)
        print("***************************************************************", flush=True)
        print(f"Spark version:{spark.version}")
        spark.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4")
        # Read
        if not query:
            input_data = spark.read.table(f"{catalog}.{input_keyspace}.{input_table}")
        else:
            input_data = spark.sql(query)
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------", flush=True)
        # Write
        print(input_data.head(), flush=True)
        input_data.write.format(constants.FORMAT_HBASE).options(catalog=catalog).option(
            "hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", "false"
        ).mode("overwrite").save()
```

Comment: It's now looking like the limit clause in the query is being ignored.